# Go to previous fragment that contains a viewpager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a fragment with a viewpager. For each fragment of viewpager you can go to another fragment. The problem is when I go back to the fragment of viewpager this is not the fragment from I went to the second fragment. What can I do for go to the same page with the same fragment when go back?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

ViewPager creates a specific amount of pages ahead - you choose it when you use setOffscreenPageLimit(amount). For example if you set the amount to be 2 then at any page in the ViewPager you'll have 2 pages created ahead and 2 created backwards.

So when you're on the 1st page - pages 2 & 3 will be created.
When you're on page 5 then you'll have 3 & 4 created and 6 & 7 created.
All others are destroyed (in case of page 5: 1,2 will be destroyed).

So it sounds that you have 2 options:
1. If you know the amount of fragments you'll have in the view pager, set the amount to be it so all pages will exist all the time. I don't like this idea because it's pretty wasteful.
2. Use a HorizontalScrollView instead of ViewPager.